# What does the comma mean in Python's unpack?

Tags: python, unpack

We can simply use:

```py
crc = struct.unpack('>i', data)
```

why do people write it like this:

```py
(crc,) = struct.unpack('>i', data)
```

What does the comma mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first variant returns a single-element tuple:

```
In [13]: crc = struct.unpack('>i', '0000')

In [14]: crc
Out[14]: (808464432,)
```

To get to the value, you have to write `crc[0]`.

The second variant *unpacks* the tuple, enabling you to write `crc` instead of `crc[0]`:

```
In [15]: (crc,) = struct.unpack('>i', '0000')

In [16]: crc
Out[16]: 808464432
```

Answer (score 2):

the `unpack` method returns a tuple of values. With the syntax you describe one can directly load the first value of the tuple into the variable `crc` while the first example has a reference to the whole tuple and you would have to access the first value by writing `crc[1]` later in the script.

So basically if you only want to use one of the return values you can use this method to directly load it in one variable.

Answer (score 1):

The comma indicates `crc` is part of a tuple. (Interestingly, it is the comma(s), not the parentheses, that indicate tuples in Python.) `(crc,)` is a tuple with one element.

```
crc = struct.unpack('>i', data)
```

makes `crc` a tuple.

```
(crc,) = struct.unpack('>i', data)
```

assigns `crc` to the value of the first (and only) element in the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

`(crc,)` is considered a one-tuple.