# Question about comma in Python and what it denotes

Tags: python, syntax

I was hoping someone could explain what the comma in between 'n' and 'digit' does.

```
while n > 0:
     n, digit = divmod(n, 10)
     total_sum = total_sum + digit ** 2
return total_sum
```

I've seen the comma been used in other situations and had always thought that, in this case, it meant that n and digit were equal to divmod(n, 10). I tried to see if the code still works but it doesn't so that doesn't seem to be the case. Could anyone explain what the comma in between the n and digit is denoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment-stmt) supports not only individual assignment but also assignment to a list of targets. This is commonly known as *unpacking*, as the elements of a ride-hand-side iterable are extracted and assigned to the names of the target list.

```py
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> print(a)
1
>>> a, b = range(2)
>>> print(a)
0
```

In specific, the `divmod(a, b)` function returns a tuple of `a // b, a % b`. Assigning to two targets assigns each term to a separate variable.

```py
>>> div, mod = divmod(1024, 10)
>>> print(div)
102
>>> print(mod)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`divmod` returns a tuple of two numbers (the devisor and remainder). Using the comma syntax allow you to assign those numbers to two different varaibles.

Answer (score 0):

n is the Quotient and digit is the remainder .
let me show a example

`n=25` and other is `10`

Quotient = 2

Remainder = 5

Answer (score 0):

It translates to:

"I expect the `divmod` function returns *something* that has exactly two parts, save me some time by getting those two parts into variables named `n` and `digit`".

The `divmod` returns two numbers. While you could do something like:

```py
x = divmod(n, 10)
n = x[0]
digit = x[1]
```

the above one-liner is far better.

Also, you can do stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894350/what-does-the-comma-mean-in-pythons-unpack):

```py
ls = ["myValue"]
(value,) = ls
print(value) #prints: myValue
```

To unpack a value from a list with single element.

Answer (score 0):

divmod is a divide and  mode, and it return the result divided and the remaining of number(here n is number and 10 is the divider)

```
n, digit = divmod(10,3)
n = 3
digit = 1
```

When you divide 10 to 3 the result is 3 and the remaining is 1